# Why syntax error messages for some built-in functions are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, cpython

I recently noticed something weird. I typed something like

```
exec code
```

And I obviously got an error. What is interesting is the error description - `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'`. I haven't found any other function that would give similarly detailed one. If I have for example

```
eval code
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. All user-defined functions and all built-ins I found, e. g. `min`, `filter`, behave the same.

Why are these error messages inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `exec code` is a valid syntax in Python 2 but not in Python 3, this error message is more detailed than a general `SyntaxError` because it was (and is) very popular (well, as popular as the usage of `exec`) when one is transitioning from Python 2 to Python 3.

You get the exact error when trying to `print string` in Python 3 (as long as `string` is defined of course).

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that. I didn't even know that `exec` was keyword in Python 2...

Answer (score 1):

The difference in errors exists because `eval` was ([in `2.x`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)) *and still is* ([in `3.x`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)) a *function call*. `exec`, on the other hand, was [a statement in `2.x`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) and [made into a function in `3.x`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).